# How do I subscribe to a question?

Tags: support

Say I discover an unanswered question that describes the exact problem I'm having, and I want to subscribe to it, so that I receive e-mail notifications whenever someone writes a comment or an answer. How do I do that?

(I have seen the 'favorite question' feature - is that the feature I want?)

Comment: I guess this should be moved to meta. Oops, Is this meta?

Answer (score 9):

You can subscribe by RSS/Atom using the "question feed" link at the bottom of the sidebar. But as far as I know there is no email notification.

Comment: Is there a way too get "inbox" notifications (red box at the top of the page)?